# how to highlight map area with extent geometry onmouse click

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, maps

I got this example in ArcGIS api sample code. But the problem is that I want to create it for any area of a map . Like if one clicks on any city, it should be selected. And the code is for mouse-over. I made it for mouse-click but this was not working. Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Feature Layer - display results as an InfoWindow onHover</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #mapDiv {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        height:100%;
      }
      #mapDiv {
        position: relative;
      }
      #info {
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
        left: 1em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        z-index: 40;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
    <script>
      var map, dialog;
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", 
        "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/graphic", "esri/lang",
        "esri/Color", "dojo/number", "dojo/dom-style", 
        "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/popup", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol,
        SimpleRenderer, Graphic, esriLang,
        Color, number, domStyle, 
        TooltipDialog, dijitPopup
      ) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-80.94, 33.646],
          zoom: 8,
          slider: false
        });

        var southCarolinaCounties = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["NAME", "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI", "POP07_SQMI"]
        });
        southCarolinaCounties.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'");

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
          SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
            new Color([255,255,255,0.35]), 
            1
          ),
          new Color([125,125,125,0.35])
        );
        southCarolinaCounties.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
        map.addLayer(southCarolinaCounties);

        map.infoWindow.resize(245,125);

        dialog = new TooltipDialog({
          id: "tooltipDialog",
          style: "position: absolute; width: 250px; font: normal normal normal 10pt Helvetica;z-index:100"
        });
        dialog.startup();

        var highlightSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
          SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, 
            new Color([255,0,0]), 3
          ), 
          new Color([125,125,125,0.35])
        );

        //close the dialog when the mouse leaves the highlight graphic
        map.on("load", function(){
          map.graphics.enableMouseEvents();
          map.graphics.on("mouse-out", closeDialog);

        });

        //listen for when the onMouseOver event fires on the countiesGraphicsLayer
        //when fired, create a new graphic with the geometry from the event.graphic and add it to the maps graphics layer
        southCarolinaCounties.on("mouse-over", function(evt){
          var t = "<b>${NAME}</b><hr><b>2000 Population: </b>${POP2000:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2000 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP00_SQMI:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2007 Population: </b>${POP2007:NumberFormat}<br>"
            + "<b>2007 Population per Sq. Mi.: </b>${POP07_SQMI:NumberFormat}";

          var content = esriLang.substitute(evt.graphic.attributes,t);
          var highlightGraphic = new Graphic(evt.graphic.geometry,highlightSymbol);
          map.graphics.add(highlightGraphic);

          dialog.setContent(content);

          domStyle.set(dialog.domNode, "opacity", 0.85);
          dijitPopup.open({
            popup: dialog, 
            x: evt.pageX,
            y: evt.pageY
          });
        });

        function closeDialog() {
          map.graphics.clear();
          dijitPopup.close(dialog);
        }

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="tundra">
    <div id="mapDiv">
      <div id="info">
        Hover over a county in South Carolina to get more information.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to change the sample to accept the mouse click.

```
        //listen for when the onMouseOver event fires on the countiesGraphicsLayer
    //when fired, create a new graphic with the geometry from the event.graphic and add it to the maps graphics layer
    southCarolinaCounties.on("click", function(evt){
        map.graphics.clear();
```

And I commented out this, so the popup doesn't disappear until you click another county

```
         //map.graphics.on("mouse-out", closeDialog);
```

If you want it to work for different data layers, you have to set those up like the South Carolina counties example. You'll have to change the highlighting style as well if you switch to point data like city dots.